# How to include research with a professor on a CV after they have moved to a different university than the one I attended

Tags: professorship, cv

I am putting together a CV detailing my research experience as I finish my PhD. I noticed that one of the professors I worked with as an undergraduate at my alma mater is now at a different university. I checked out their lab website at the new university and it seems the graduate students who were working with them at the time transferred with them after I left the lab. I'm not sure how to list my research experience now that they are a university I was never enrolled at.

Do I list the name of the lab at my alma mater but link to the professor's contact information at their new university if someone reading my CV wishes to talk with them?

Comment: Your idea is how I would do it. Where you conducted the research did not change, just the professor’s contact info. There’s no point putting outdated contact info in your CV for the sake of posterity

Comment: @Spark that doesn't particularly address my question. Should I include a link to contact this professor even though they are not at my alma mater?

Comment: Are you using that professor as one of the recommendation letter writer? If not, why do you need to list the professor's contact info? If whoever reads your CV and wants to contact the prof, they either will contact the prof directly or ask you, then you can tell them the contact info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did the research at the institution you attended, so that's what you should list on your CV.

It's not typical to put contact information for a professor on your CV, but if you'd like to make sure they are easy to find you can certainly add a note.

I'd do something like:

> Undergraduate Researcher, Dr. I. Newton lab (now at Apple University)

Comment: Thank you, that's better than what I had written.